# $\epsilon$, $\delta$ are positive infinitesimal, is the following expression infinitesimal, finite, or infite?

Tags: calculus, infinitesimals

I'm going through problems in chapter one of Elementary Calculus: An Infinitesimal Approach by H. Jerome Keisler.

I need some help with question 39 in Section 1.5 problems.

$\epsilon$, $\delta$ are positive infinitesimal, is the following expression infinitesimal, finite, or infite?

The expression is this:

$$\frac{\epsilon + \delta}{\sqrt{\epsilon^2 + \delta^2}}$$

It also gives the following hint:

> (Hint: Assume $\epsilon \ge \delta$ and divide through by $\epsilon$)

The answer is finite.

I got some semblance of a solution, but I really don't understand fully how to communicate it or how rigorous it is. I think I need some schooling on this one...

$$\frac{1+\frac{\delta}{\epsilon}}{\frac{\sqrt{\epsilon^2 + \delta^2}}{\epsilon}}$$

Because $\epsilon \ge \delta$ we know that the radicand is no greater than $2\epsilon^2$

\begin{align}
\frac{1+\frac{\delta}{\epsilon}}{\frac{\sqrt{\epsilon^2 + \delta^2}}{\epsilon}}
& = \frac{1+\frac{\delta}{\epsilon}}{\frac{\sqrt{2\epsilon^2}}{\epsilon}} \\
& = \frac{1+\frac{\delta}{\epsilon}}{\frac{\epsilon\sqrt{2}}{\epsilon}} \\
& = \frac{1+\frac{\delta}{\epsilon}}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{align}

$\frac{\delta}{\epsilon}$ What is this part? Finite? I don't know if this term is finite or infinitesimal. Either way the result is finite.

> The suggested alternative solution doesn't address this question about $\frac{\delta}{\epsilon}$. Also my general curiosity about the logic of my approach is not address in the alternative question.

Please correct me here if I got to the answer the wrong way and fill me in on my missing understanding.

thanks.

Comment: How these terms are defined? 'Finite', 'Infinitesimal' and 'Infinite'?

Comment: Well actually, I was lazy, the finite one is actually defined as "finite but not infinitesimal" in the book.

Comment: @YathirajSharma This book defines these numbers on a hyperreal numberline. This book is downloadable for free to look more into these definitions. Too much to write here I think.

Comment: @YathirajSharma the book defines a positive infinitesimal hyperreal number to be positive but less than every positive real number.

Comment: Btw, you gave an expression but didn't state what the problem is

Comment: @Sgg8 exact question is now in the question body.

Comment: @Sgg8 I your alternative suggestion and it doesn't answer my specific question about $\frac{\delta}{\epsilon}$. Also it doesn't address my curiosity about my approach. I would rather let some more eyeballs get on my question.

Comment: "The answer is infinite." Why do you say this? Your reason for saying this should be part of the question so that we know what we are responding to.

Comment: @DavidK From the context, it seemed clear to me that that "the answer is infinite" came from some authority like the textbook, the teacher, etc. Weakly supporting evidence is that that is indeed the correct answer. (But this doesn't matter for this question since it's a duplicate)

Comment: @MarkS yes you're right, thank you. I was saying it was the answer in the back of the book..giving more information to the readers of this question.

Comment: @DavidK my apologies and apologies to everyone here for wasting your time. The answer in the back of the book was finite. Not infinite. Sorry for being a #&*@...

Comment: @MarkS. Actually "infinite" is not the correct answer, which was why I asked. But this is all cleared up now, and really no trouble.

Comment: @MarkS sorry for this, and Sgg8 and Yathiraj